# How can I add this "not assigned" partition to SDA6?

Tags: partitioning

[image: GParted view]

How can I add this "not assigned" partition to SDA6 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move `/dev/sda3` (and its contents `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7`) right after `/dev/sda2`; this will take a long time and is risky so do backup your important data in `/dev/sda6`. Then you can delete the swap partition `/dev/sda7`, recreate it at the end of the disk, and expand `/dev/sda6` to fill in the free space which should then be after it.

Comment: Thank you fkraiem. I'll do it tomorrow (it's 1:47 am here) and hope it works.